# Clicking a button using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests

I am trying to automate something on Facebook using Python selenium. I want to click the post button shown in the second image. When I click the inspect in chrome on this post button, it takes me to the highlighted 'class' element shown in the third image. To click this button, I have tried the following:

```
#browser.find_element_by_class_name("oajrlxb2 s1i5eluu qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 pq6dq46d p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x cxgpxx05 d1544ag0 sj5x9vvc tw6a2znq oqcyycmt esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl l9j0dhe7 abiwlrkh p8dawk7l ehryuci6 bp9cbjyn beltcj47 p86d2i9g aot14ch1 kzx2olss rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 lrazzd5p gigivrx4 sf5mxxl7 g0qnabr5 lrwzeq9o iqfcb0g7 lsqurvkf id6903cd jq4qci2q m5l1wtfr taijpn5t sn7ne77z oqhjfihn bwm1u5wc").click()
```

Following is the error I am getting:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this class the same for all the posts?

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: Pls check out my solution and let me know whether it works for u.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed is that the `div` tag contains the text `Post`, so instead of complicating things with the `class name`, you can simply click on the element by identifying the text it contains. You can do it like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Post')]")
```